# Session Login And Logout

Tags: php, session, authentication, admin

İ entered username='admin' pw='admin'on my login.php that’s values true on mysqladmin

Thank you for your helps.

i cant check to login admin page.I can open admin.php without username and pw.

Here is the codes

check_login.php

```
        <?php
define(DOC_ROOT,dirname(__FILE__)); // To properly get the config.php file
$username = $_POST['username']; //Set UserName
$password = $_POST['password']; //Set Password
$msg ='';
if(isset($username, $password)) {
    ob_start();
    include(DOC_ROOT.'/config.php'); //Initiate the MySQL connection
    // To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
    $myusername = stripslashes($username);
    $mypassword = stripslashes($password);
    $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbC, $myusername);
    $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbC, $mypassword);
    $sql="SELECT * FROM login_admin WHERE user_name='$myusername' and user_pass=SHA('$mypassword')";
    $result=mysqli_query($dbC, $sql);
    // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
    if($count==1){
        // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "admin.php" 
        $_SESSION["admin"]= $myusername;
        $_SESSION["password"]= $mypassword;
        $_SESSION["name"]= $myusername;
        header("location:admin.php");
    }
    else {
        $msg = "Wrong Username or Password. Please retry";
        header("location:login.php?msg=$msg");
    }
    ob_end_flush();
}
else {
    header("location:login.php?msg=Please enter some username and password");
}
```

admin.php

```
    <?php
 //Get the user name from the previously registered super global variable
session_start(); //Start the session
define(ADMIN,$_SESSION['name']); //Get the user name from the previously registered super global variable
if( isset($_SESSION['admin']) && $_SESSION['admin'] == '0' ){

header('location:login.php'); // Redirect to login.php page
}
else //Continue to current page

header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <h1>Welcome To Admin Page <?php echo $_SESSION['admin'] ?></h1>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome To Admin Page <?php echo ADMIN /*Echo the username */ ?></h1>
    <p><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></p> <!-- A link for the logout page -->
    <p>Put Admin Contents</p>
</body>
</html>
```

İ tryed something about session fonction but did not work.

Comment: I see no `session_start()` in the `check_login.php` file. And put an [exit](http://php.net//manual/en/function.exit.php) or [die](http://php.net//manual/en/function.die.php) after each redirect header, because it's a security hole.

Comment: You should also redirect in the case where `$_SESSION['admin']` is _not_ set (in admin.php).

Comment: Sidenote: Some browsers wont follow relative "Location: xxx" redirects. You should try to use absolute ones.